# Navigation bar and fixed floating contact bar click and stay open, change font as well

Tags: html, css, fonts, navigation, nav

I need help trying to change two things with the navigation and floating fixed contact bar on my website page:

1. the font to match the rest of the website
2. making it click and stay open, click and close

**This is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Website Project</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Vancouver Island University</h1>
    <h1>Health and Wellness Community</h1>
    <h1>"No more excuses"</h1>
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="Images/VIU-logo-small.jpg" alt="VIU logo" title="VIU logo"></a>
</header>
<img src="Images/websitebackground.jpg" id="background" alt="website background image">
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events and Workshops</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Upcoming Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Request an Event or Workshop</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Nutrition Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Physical Activity Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mental Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Spiritual Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Medical Health Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Volunteer Opportunities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/blog.png" alt="Blog Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span> Blog </span></span>
            <iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <div id="articlepreview"><h2>Glorifying Exhaustion: The student crisis</h2><p>It’s that time of year again; between the midterms, papers, and looming final exams, people start to brag about how they are on their sixth extra-large triple-shot coffee, or that they pulled an all-nighter to get their paper in on time...</p></div>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.thenav.ca/2016/11/16/glorifying-exhaustion-the-student-crisis/">
            <img id="articleimage" src="Images/articleimage.jpg" alt="Resource Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Resources</span></span>
            <iframe id="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/upcomingevents.png" alt="Upcoming Events Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Upcoming Events</span></span>
            <iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/volunteer.png" alt="Volunteer Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Volunteer</span></span>
            <iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="http://blog.myfitnesspal.com/10-nutritious-smoothies-250-calories/">
            <img src="Images/smoothies.jpg" alt="Nutrition Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Nutrition</span></span>
            <iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
        </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <div id="articlepreview"><h2>I Want To Be With Someone Who Knows What It’s Like To Be Broken</h2><p>When seeking a partner, most people have pretty generic things that they’re looking for. They want a man to be handsome, smart, successful, funny, kind. But most qualities that people rattle off don’t go much deeper than that. For me, there’s something rare and unconventional I’m looking for in another person. A quality that I know will mean I truly found the right partner...</p></div>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://thoughtcatalog.com/kelly-bishop/2016/03/i-want-to-be-with-someone-who-knows-what-its-like-to-be-broken/">
            <img id="articleimage" src="Images/mentalhealth.jpg" alt="Mental Health Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Resources</span></span>
            <iframe id="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<aside>
    <ul id="emergencycontact">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3>
                <h4>Assistance Phones</h4>
                <p class="underline"><a href="https://www2.viu.ca/facilities/docs/VIU-AssistancePhones-Map.pdf">Location Map</a></p>
                <h4>Vancouver Island University Counselling Services</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 8 am - 4 pm</p>
                <p>Nanaimo Campus   Phone: 250-740-6416</p>
                <p>Cowichan Campus Phone: 250-746-3509</p>
                <p>Parksville Campus    Phone: 250-248-2096</p>
                <p>Powell River Campus  Phone: (604) 485-2878</p>
                <h4>Mental Health Walk-in Clinic (Crisis Counselling)</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 10am - 6pm</p>
                <p>Nanaimo  Phone: 250-739-5710</p>
                <p>Location: 203-2000 Island Highway North, Nanaimo, BC V9S 5W3</p>
                <p class="underline"><a href="http://www.viha.ca/mhas/locations/nanaimo/">Island Health: Mental Health and Substance Abuse services</a></p>
                <h4>Vancouver Island Crisis Line</h4>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 1-888-494-3888</p>
                <p class="underline"><a href="http://www.vicrisis.ca/">Vancouver Island Crisis Line</a></p>
                <h4>Haven Transition House Crisis Line Support for abused women and their children</h4>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 250-756-0616</p>
                <h4>On Campus Emergency</h4>
                <p class="contactheading">Emergency, First Aid, Security, Ambulance, Fire, Police, Bomb Threat</p>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Nanaino/Cowichan Phone: 6600</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Powell River   Phone: 8121 or 911</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Parksville Phone: 951-3000 or 911</p>
                <p class="contactheading">Emergency Phone   Push button</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Nanaimo    Phone: 740-6600</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Cowichan   Phone: 1-250-740-6600</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Powell River   Phone: 604-485-2878</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Parksville Phone: 951-3000 or 911</p>
                <h4>Off Campus Emergency</h4>
                <p class="contactheading">Police, Fire, and Ambulance Services</p>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 911</p>
                <h4>Nanaimo Regional General Hospital</h4>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 250-754-2141</p>
                <p>Location: 1200 Dufferin Crescent, Nanaimo, BC V9S 5R6</p>
                <h4>Email contact</h4>
                <p class="underline">behealthy@viu.ca</p>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
<footer>
    <p id="validator">Valid: <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fmediastudies.viu.ca%2FStudents%2F577081557%2FLabs%2Flab02.html">HTML 5</a> | <a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmediastudies.viu.ca%2FStudents%2F577081557%2FLabs%2Findex.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en">CSS 3</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
 html {
        min-width: 100%;
    }

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden; /*Disable horizontal scrollbar*/
    }

#background /*Background image*/
{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;  
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -4;
  opacity: .5;
}
*
{
    font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, Arial;
}
header
{
    background-color: #144762; /*VIU colours*/
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
#logo
{
    float: left;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    
}
h1
{
    margin-left: 500px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Navigation Menu, <nav>*/
#menu /*entire box*/
{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;/*#444 the Navigator nav color*/
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu li /*text box*/
{
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ecffec;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
}
#menu ul /*Actual dropdown menu*/
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    width: auto;
}

#menu ul li /*text inside dropdown menu*/
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
#menu li:hover
{
    background-color: #ffd98a;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}

/*Contact information*/
#emergencycontact /*entire box, <aside>*/
{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0; 
    position: fixed;/*added this*/
    width: 120px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
}
#emergencycontact li /*text box*/
{
    border: 1px solid #ecffec;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
}
#emergencycontact ul /*Actual popout window*/
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    right:0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0 0 26px 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
h4, p.contactheading, p.italic, #emergencycontact p/*text inside dropdown menu*/
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}

#emergencycontact a:link, #emergencycontact a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
#emergencycontact li:hover
{
    background-color: #ffd98a;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#emergencycontact li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}
p.underline
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
p.italic
{
    font-style: italic;
}
.heading
{
    text-align: center;
}

/*Sectional blocks*/
section
{
    margin: 40px 23px;
    width: 100%;
}
div.sectionalblocks 
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -2; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
div.sectionalblocks img /*Image underneath sectional blocks*/
{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    
    
}
#articleimage /*Image underneath article*/
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    filter: brightness(80%);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#articlepreview /*Text inside article sectional blocks*/
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
#articlepreview h2 /*Header text inside article sectional blocks*/
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
span.text-content /*Text inside sectional blocks*/
{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    font-family:"proxima nova",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:3;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
span.text-content span 
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.text-content:hover 
{
    opacity:1;
}
iframe.likebutton
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
#likebutton
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
}

/*Footer*/
#validator
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-70px;
    left: 20px;
    width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fonts issue you are having is on your menu selection:

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma; /*Right Here*/
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You should either leave that line out or make it the same:

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, Arial;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

If you need the menu to remain open on a click it would be best to use JavaScript or jQuery. You can leave what you have for the hover state, but add a class to the same selection, like "show", for example. Then toggling the class on click will do the trick.

For simplicity here is a sample in jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#menu li:hover, #menu li.show
{
    background-color: #ffd98a;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li.show ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the font fix change this in the CSS

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    ...
#emergencycontact a:link, #emergencycontact a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    ...
```

To this:

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma;
    ...
#emergencycontact a:link, #emergencycontact a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma;
    ...
```

For the contact menu, you can accomplish that with CSS (No JS required):

HTML

```
<aside>
  <ul id="emergencycontact">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="contact"/>
      <label for="contact" name="contact">Contact</label>
      <ul>
        <h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3>
        <h4>Assistance Phones</h4>
        ...
```

CSS

```
#emergencycontact li:hover,
#emergencycontact input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ffd98a;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#emergencycontact li:hover ul,
#emergencycontact input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}

#emergencycontact input {
  display: none;
}

#emergencycontact label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px; /* or whatever */
}
```

And to get the "stay open" behavior on the nav menu:

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="events-and-workshops"/>
      <label for="events-and-workshops">Events and Workshops</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
        ...
```

CSS

```
#menu a:link,
#menu a:visited,
#menu label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

#menu li:hover,
#menu input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ffd98a;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu li:hover ul,
#menu input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brett! But how would I achieve the "click to remain open" effect with my navigation menu? I tried doing the same thing with the emergency contact bar, but it didn't have the same effect! :(

Comment: You could do the same thing with the checkbox/label and sibling selector trick.

Comment: I tried that, and now when I click, the main navigation bar doesn't stay highlighted, and the sub menu stays open but doesn't highlight anything on hover.

Also, my default font-weight:bold gets overwritten to normal.

Comment: Double check your CSS. It's just a matter of styling that label to look like the rest of the links.

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work, the menu doesn't highlight once it's clicked (although it stays open), and it doesn't highlight anything in the sub menu :(

Comment: #menu a:link, #menu a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
#menu li:hover 
{
    background-color: #ffd98a;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu li:hover ul
{
 display: block;
}

#menu li:hover,
# input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ffd98a;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu li:hover ul,
#menu input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
 }

#menu input {
  display: none;}
#menu label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px; }

Comment: Take out #menu label { display: block; padding: 5px; }, and do this, #menu a:link, #menu a:visited, #menu label { display: block; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; color: #000; padding: 5px; }. I wouldn't highlight the whole submenu though, because you want each item to be highlighted on hover.

Comment: Tried that, still isn't staying highlighted upon click, and the highlight on hover still doesn't work for the sub menu items :(

Comment: I have it working like I think you want it here: http://codepen.io/bap13/pen/BQmNNQ?editors=1010

Comment: The highlight upon click is now working, but the sub menu highlight works on the codepen link you gave me, but not on my browser? I tried it on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: Here is one version too, and it doesn't seem to highlight on hover over the sub menu here either: https://jsfiddle.net/nxb8bann/1/

Comment: Your footer#validator is on top of the menu. You can move it or add #validator { z-index: -1; }